# DropdownListFor doesn't show the selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am so confused how to make the dropdownlist to show the selected value.

Model:

```
public class SampleModel
{        
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditInformation()
{
    ViewBag.State = new SelectList(db.States, "StateName", "StateName");

    string userEmail = User.Identity.GetUserName();

    Sample model = new SampleModel();     
    model.State = "Melbourne";

    return View(model);
}
```

View :

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.State, ViewBag.State as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select State --")
```

The list is showing the states just fine, but it doesn't automatically select the value I assigned ("Melbourne"). I have tried using the selectlist constructor to assign the selectedValue, but after doing a lot of research, someone wrote that it is redundant to use the selectlist constructor if you are using `Html.DropdownListFor()` since you will be using the value assigned to the model.

EDIT:

Here is my db.State model:

```
public class State
{
    [Key]
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }

}
```

Again to clarify, I want to use StateName as the value and the text for the selectlistitem.

EDIT:
My full action method:

```
public ActionResult EditInformation()
    {
        //var states = ndb.States.Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.StateName, Value = s.StateName , Selected = s.StateName == "Jawa Timur" }).ToList();

        ViewBag.State = new SelectList(ndb.States, "StateName", "StateName");
        ViewBag.City = new SelectList(ndb.Cities, "CityName", "CityName");
        string[] countries = { "Indonesia" };
        ViewBag.Country = new SelectList(countries);

        string userEmail = User.Identity.GetUserName();
        try
        {
            UserInformation userInfo = ndb.UserInformations.Single(m => m.Email == userEmail);
            UserAccountViewModel model = new UserAccountViewModel();

            model.Address = userInfo.Address;
            model.Email = userEmail;
            model.FirstName = userInfo.FirstName;
            model.LastName = userInfo.LastName;
            model.Phone = userInfo.Phone;
            model.PostalCode = userInfo.PostalCode;
            Debug.Print(userInfo.State);
            model.State = userInfo.State;
            model.City = userInfo.City;
            model.Country = userInfo.Country;


            return View(model);
        }catch { }
        return View();

    }
```

Comment: What is your `db.States` look like?

Comment: why did you post a model of `SampleModel` then stuff your ViewBag with something from `db.States`?  Post your model for `States`.  Does your `db.States` have an `ID`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid, actually there is more to the model, I just simplify it so you guys can read better, the rest is just simple property and they are working as expected. my db.States have an ID, but i prefer using the name as the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ActionResult EditInformation(int? id /*this will be passed from your route values in your view*/)
{
    State myState = db.States.Find(id)


    ViewBag.State = new SelectList(ndb.States, "StateId", "StateName", myState.StateId);
}//I only added this because this is what the question pertains to.
```

In your EditInformation View you need to have an actionlink to link to the user's id so that you pull up the right information, so:

EditInformation View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit Information", "EditInformation", /*Controller Name if this view is rendered from a different controller*/, new { id = item.id })
}
```

Comment: what if I want the name as the value? not the id

Comment: @StewartJingga So you have tried this solution and it renders the `ID` and not the `State`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid i tried using the StateId and still it doesnt work.

Comment: @StewartJingga what is happening? it's not working at all or it is displaying the `ID`?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid It is showing the list perfectly, but it doesnt select the selected value automatically.

Comment: @StewartJingga so when you open your View it shows '-- Select State --' and not the value that you want to show?

Comment: @StewartJingga okay so if you want the view to show a specific value.. then why have '-- Select State --' in there as at all?

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid because the form is going to be dynamic, if user has entered a value for state previously, I want them to see it first when they want to edit the information, but if this is the first time a user want to input their information, -- Select State -- will be default option.

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid anyway I have tried removing the --select state--, and it showed the first array in the list rather than the selected value.

Comment: @StewartJingga ahhhhh okay so when a user selects a value and saves.. then wants to go back to edit that information it should show the value that they previously selected?

Comment: @StewartJingga if you have trouble please post your `Edit` Action so I can see it and hopefully get a better understanding

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I have tried your update and still it is just showing the list, also what do you mean in [HttpPost] the problem is in the GET.

Comment: @StewartJingga Yeah sorry, I was thinking of something else.. i edited my code

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I have posted the full action method

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I have posted the solution, thanks for bearing with me! really appreciate it! :*

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class SampleModel
{        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditInformation()
{
    //Select default value like this (of course if your db.States have an Id):
    ViewBag.State = new SelectList(db.States, "Id", "StateName", 1 /*Default Value Id or Text*/);
    . . .
    return View();
}
```

> `SelectList(IEnumerable, String, String, Object)` - Initializes a new instance of the SelectList class by using the specified items for the list, the data value field, the data text field, **and a selected value**.

View:

```
@Html.DropdownList("State", null, "-- Select State --")
```

Or Like you do:

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.State, ViewBag.State as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select State --")
```

UPDATE:

You can get Selected text using jQuery like so:
Add `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.State)`

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.State, ViewBag.State as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "-- Select State --", new { id = "stateId" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.State)
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
$("form").submit(function(){
    var selectedText= $("#stateId :selected").text();
    $("#State").val(selTypeText);           
  });
});
```

Post:

```
[HttpPost]
public void UploadDocument(State model)
{
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      string state = model.State;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want the value of the selectlistitem to be the same as the text.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I am more concerned about what causes it rather than making it works.

Comment: What happening when you replacing `ViewBag.State = new SelectList(db.States, "Id", "StateName", 1);` to `ViewBag.State = new SelectList(db.States, "StateName", "StateName", "Melbourne");`

Comment: using your recommended solution, I had to change the model.State property to integer, and it was still showing the list but It didnt select the selected value or the value that is in the model.

Comment: You don't need to change model.State to integer, you just need to create your `SelectList` with Text and Value then bind it to `DropDowList`, after using jQuery you can get the selected Text value from `DropDownList`, this is a solution in your case.

Comment: Hi Sem, thanks for your help, but I found the error, this one is really tough to spot.

Answer (score 0):

OKAY, So after researching for quite some time, the problem lies in the naming convention. Apparently, you cannot use `ViewBag.State` for `Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.State)`, this somehow causes the `Html.DropdownListFor(m => m.State)` to not reading the data properly.

Comment: so you changed it to @Html.DropDownList("State", null, --Select State--)

Comment: nope, I changed the `ViewBag,State` to `ViewBag.States`, as long as it is not State (without s because it is the property of the model) it will work. You should use `ViewBag.State` if you are using `DropdownList` because there you can't assign name and id for the form.